# How to log the System memory and number of thread in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, monitoring

log the System memory  and number of thread in Spring Boot?
Show memory dump - number of threads open, amount of being memory being used, amount of memory allocated

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spring-boot actuator` dependency to gather information of your application `metrics`.

Not everything, but you will certainly be able to find out memory and related information

**Read about actuator here**

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-actuators

[https://springframework.guru/actuator-in-spring-boot/#:~:text=Spring%20Boot%20Actuator%20is%20a,metrics%20from%20production%2Dready%20applications](https://springframework.guru/actuator-in-spring-boot/#:%7E:text=Spring%20Boot%20Actuator%20is%20a,metrics%20from%20production%2Dready%20applications).